# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <user url>

Tags: java, birt

i am using birt-2_6_1 with tomcat 7 along with eclipse IDE to generate reports. i have done the coding for generating chart and save them in tem location as png format. but when i am exporting those images in my downloadable pdf file it is not showing those images into downloaded file neither in pdf format nor in excel format. is it throwing this exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Softwares/new_tomcat/tomcat7/temp/jfreechart-299441806335424490.png
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ImageReader.readImage(ImageReader.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.ImageAreaLayout.initialize(ImageAreaLayout.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.ImageAreaLayout.layout(ImageAreaLayout.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContent(LayoutEngine.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startImage(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.CompositeContentEmitter.startImage(CompositeContentEmitter.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.HTMLPageBuffer.startContent(HTMLPageBuffer.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.TableBreakBuffer.startContent(TableBreakBuffer.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLeafItemLM.start(HTMLLeafItemLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.i10n.fleet.util.ReportExporter.**exportReport(ReportExporter.java:98**)
    at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportOperations.**ExportVehicleReport(ExportReportOperations.java:596)**
    at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportOperations.**generateVehicleReport(ExportReportOperations.java:497)**
    at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportsController.**processRequest(ExportReportsController.java:131)**
    at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.ExportReportsController.**handleRequestInternal(ExportReportsController.java:71)**
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at com.i10n.fleet.web.controllers.CascadedFormController.handleRequest(CascadedFormController.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:282)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

all the above bold letter files i am using for this task. but it is showing error in this line:

```
vehicleReportTask.run();
```

where `vehicleReportTask` is the `RunAndRenderTask` which is holding the png images to diplay in reports. This is how i am storing into task:

```
vehicleReportTask.setParameterValue("image", imgPath + filename);
```

its giving the same error from long time now, so if anyone can help me resolving this issue it would be veru much helpful to me. if anything required as an input feel free to ask.
i can mail you of needed my email id is: vikramfartyal@gmail.com

Comment: Try with absolute path of the png image in PDF/Excel file generation code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol` means lack of protocol, like `http://` of `file://`.

Try to pass URL like this: `file:///Softwares/new_tomcat/tomcat7/temp/jfreechart-299441806335424490.png` by adding protocol prefix to `imgPath`.